# Register sidebar 'before' and 'after' html as div rather than li tags

Tags: theme-development, widgets, register-sidebar

I am making sidebars for my theme using the register sidebar function. The codex does it something like this

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array(
'name' => 'Right Sidebar',
'id' => 'right-sidebar',
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget' => '</li>',
'before_title' => '<h4>',
'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
```

however [Jason Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/08/sidebars-in-wordpress) does it something like this:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array(
'name' => 'Right Sidebar',
'id' => 'right-sidebar',
'before_widget' => '<div>',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '<h4>',
'after_title' => '</h4>',
));

ie that (causes the dynamic_sidebar function to ) output 
<ul><div> ... etc ... </div><div> ... etc ... </div></ul> 
using no <li> tags becuase of the before and after widget paramaters
```

I have found nothing on the w3c that allows anything other than < li > tags inside < ul > tags, but yet I cant imagine Justin Tadlock endorsing invlaid code.

To be honest Justin's way makes a bit more sense to me semantically but I'm sure others would differ. My questions are - is it ok to do it this way? .... and which is best ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dynamic_sidebar()` does not output a `<ul>`, so what your code should look like is as follows:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
```

and that, along with `<div>` tags in before_widget and after_widget, will give you nested divs.

Comment: Yes I see now I had thought that the UL was generated by wordpress but I must have been looking via firebug when I looked closer at the actual file I see it was actually in my code around dynamic_sidebar. Thanks, that explains it.